# SIMCom SIM808 SD card problem

Tags: at-commands, sdcard

I am working with SIMCom's SIM808 2G+GPS modem and trying to connect it to an SD card.  I am following SIMCom hardware design docs, to save some data in SD memory.

The problem is: when I send command "AT+SD2PCM=1" to the module, it returns ERROR message. Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I have read the relevant documentation.bat i reply error on"AT+SD2PCM=?"  command.do you help me? please.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [this document](https://codius.ru/file/download/4f7cb937-b8a7-4e28-bd24-c23d9a03c9da) ?

Setting mode = 1 means "**PCM interface is valid**".

Setting to 0 means SD card.

Also, in these cases, you should generally try the query command first - to see its response:
**AT+SD2PCM=?**